# CPython Parsing Argument for Long Double (for PyArg_ParseTuple)

Tags: python, c, cpython

I've been using the C Python API to implement some functions in C. I came across the `PyArg_ParseTuple()` function which takes in arguments and parses them to give to the C function.

The [API documentations](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html) list the different characters that are used are arguments to parse. For example, `iKd` would mean `integer`, `unsigned long long`, and `double`. However, I cannot find the argument for parsing a `long double`. I've looked at many different documentation sites but haven't gotten anything. What symbol can I use to parse a `long double`?